# ClassNotFoundException on akka.remote.RemoteActorRefProvider

Tags: java, eclipse, scala

I am trying to communicate between remote actors in scala using the Akka actors. My program runs fine from scala IDE but I am unable to run it from command prompt. In my project folder, I have the application.conf file, scala file and akka-remote_2.10-2.2.2.jar file. I am compiling my program as follows

```
scalac -cp akka-remote_2.10-2.2.2.jar FileName.scala
```

The program compiles and then I run it as follows

```
scala FileName
```

I get the following error

```
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: akka.remote.RemoteActorRefProvider
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:202)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:190)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:306)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:247)
    at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
    at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:247)
    at akka.actor.ReflectiveDynamicAccess$$anonfun$getClassFor$1.apply(Dynam
icAccess.scala:68)
    at akka.actor.ReflectiveDynamicAccess$$anonfun$getClassFor$1.apply(Dynam
icAccess.scala:67)
    at scala.util.Try$.apply(Try.scala:161)
    at akka.actor.ReflectiveDynamicAccess.getClassFor(DynamicAccess.scala:67
)
    at akka.actor.ReflectiveDynamicAccess.createInstanceFor(DynamicAccess.sc
ala:85)
    at akka.actor.ActorSystemImpl.<init>(ActorSystem.scala:546)
    at akka.actor.ActorSystem$.apply(ActorSystem.scala:111)
    at akka.actor.ActorSystem$.apply(ActorSystem.scala:93)
    at Project1Bonus2$.main(Project1Bonus2.scala:11)
    at Project1Bonus2.main(Project1Bonus2.scala)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.
java:39)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAcces
sorImpl.java:25)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
    at scala.tools.nsc.util.ScalaClassLoader$$anonfun$run$1.apply(ScalaClass
Loader.scala:71)
    at scala.tools.nsc.util.ScalaClassLoader$class.asContext(ScalaClassLoade
r.scala:31)
    at scala.tools.nsc.util.ScalaClassLoader$URLClassLoader.asContext(ScalaC
lassLoader.scala:139)
    at scala.tools.nsc.util.ScalaClassLoader$class.run(ScalaClassLoader.scal
a:71)
    at scala.tools.nsc.util.ScalaClassLoader$URLClassLoader.run(ScalaClassLo
ader.scala:139)
    at scala.tools.nsc.CommonRunner$class.run(ObjectRunner.scala:28)
    at scala.tools.nsc.ObjectRunner$.run(ObjectRunner.scala:45)
    at scala.tools.nsc.CommonRunner$class.runAndCatch(ObjectRunner.scala:35)

    at scala.tools.nsc.ObjectRunner$.runAndCatch(ObjectRunner.scala:45)
    at scala.tools.nsc.MainGenericRunner.runTarget$1(MainGenericRunner.scala
:74)
    at scala.tools.nsc.MainGenericRunner.process(MainGenericRunner.scala:96)

    at scala.tools.nsc.MainGenericRunner$.main(MainGenericRunner.scala:105)
    at scala.tools.nsc.MainGenericRunner.main(MainGenericRunner.scala)
```

My application.conf file is as follows.

```
akka {
actor {
provider = "akka.remote.RemoteActorRefProvider"
}
remote {
enabled-transports = ["akka.remote.netty.tcp"]
netty.tcp {
hostname = "127.0.0.1"
port = 9001
}
}
}
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: Also, running the program using scala -cp akka-remote_2.10-2.2.2.jar FileName also gives the same exception.

Comment: Please post full exception for `scala -cp akka-remote_2.10-2.2.2.jar`

Comment: Did you add `akka-remote_2.10-2.2.2.jar` to the CLASSPATH?

Comment: @1esha It gives the same exception as above..

Comment: @zsxwing Yes I did add it to the classpath. The dependancies are the same when I use command line, eclipse or sbt. It works with eclipse and sbt. Doesnt work with command line, still gives the same exception.

Comment: I am seeing this same error when running Spark (which uses akka). There are several posts about it including this one, none show it resolved.

Answer (score 0):

The problem here is that the Scala distribution contains akka-actor 2.X.X in its boot class path by default. Hence, the one used by *scalac* and *scala* in your code are different.

The workaround is to use java to launch the application instead of scala. All you need to do is to include the right Scala jars (scala-library and scala-compiler) in the classpath.

```
java -cp akka-remote_2.10-2.2.2.jar FileName.scala
```

There are going to be many jar dependencies e.g akka-actor etc.

Therefore, use SBT or put all jars in a folder and then add that folder in the class path.

```
java -cp ./jars/*:. FileName.scala
```

Answer (score 0):

What solved the issue for me was importing the akka-remote dependency. Add the following line to the `build.sbt` file.

```
libraryDependencies += "com.typesafe.akka" %% "akka-remote" % "2.5.32"
```